Writing a sector in a flash device
I have written a C++ code with Visual Studio 2022 on Windiws 11, which writes a sector into a removable flash device (D:)
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void writeSector(size_t position, const uint8_t* buffer, DWORD sectorSize)
{
    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFileA(
    "\\\\.\\D:",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL
    );

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error opening device: " + GetLastError());
    }

    DWORD bytesWritten;
    LARGE_INTEGER li = { 0 };
    li.QuadPart = position;
    if (!SetFilePointerEx(hDevice, li, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    {
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        throw std::runtime_error("Impossible to set file pointer: " + GetLastError());
    }
    BOOL bRet = WriteFile(hDevice, buffer, sectorSize, &bytesWritten, NULL);

    if (!bRet)
    {
        std::string msg = "WriteFile returned 0 " + GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.c_str());
    }

    if (bytesWritten != sectorSize)
    {
        std::string msg = "Written bytes different than expected: " + std::to_string(bytesWritten) + " " + GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.c_str());
    }

    CloseHandle(hDevice);
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t buffer[512] = {0};
    writeSector(0, buffer, 512);
    writeSector(1024*512, buffer, 512);
    writeSector(10*1024*512, buffer, 512);
}

All the checks contained in the function writeSector() are successful except the last one, where the number of actually written bytes bytesWritten is compared with the expected value  sectorSize. In fact, the value of bytesWritten is 0. The GetLastError() returns 0: so theoretically there hasn't been an error: simply, nothing has been written.
Maybe I am writing at wrong addresses or with invalid size?
The geometry of the device, read by DeviceIoControl(), is: {Cylinders={253689} MediaType=RemovableMedia (11) TracksPerCylinder=255 BytesPerSector = 512}.

Edit - I rewrote this function by using the NtWriteFile() of Windows kit, and I have the same result:
void writeSectorNt(size_t position, const uint8_t* buffer, DWORD sectorSize)
{
    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFileA(
    "\\\\.\\D:",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open device: " + GetLastErrorString());
    }

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock = { 0 };

    LARGE_INTEGER li = { 0 };
    li.QuadPart = position;
    NTSTATUS status = NtWriteFile(
        hDevice,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &ioStatusBlock,
        (PVOID)buffer,
        (ULONG)sectorSize,
        &li,
        NULL
        );

    int testErr = GetLastError();
    if (status < 0 || testErr)
    {
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        throw std::runtime_error("NtWriteFile failed with status: " + std::to_string(status));

    }

    CloseHandle(hDevice);
}

The call of the function is successful (both the return value and the GetLastError()).
However, although this function doesn't provide as output the number of actually written bytes, if I read the sector at the same address, I can see that the the contents was not actually written.
Possibly there is something wrong either with the logic of this code, or with the behavior of the Usbstick. Maybe it is not compatible with the geometry of the device... How could I try to change the function, or the address / size that I'm using when I call it?

EDIT 28.06.2024
I changed the parameters of CreateFileA():
    static bool writeSector(size_t position, const uint8_t* buffer, DWORD sectorSize)
{
    HANDLE hVolume = CreateFileA(
        "\\\\.\\D:",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    if (hVolume == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hVolume == 0)
    {
        long lastErr = (long)GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error opening device: error " << lastErr;
        return false;
    }

    DWORD bytesWritten;
    LARGE_INTEGER li = { 0 };
    li.QuadPart = position;
    if (!SetFilePointerEx(hVolume, li, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    {
        long lastErr = (long)GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Impossible to set file pointer: error " << lastErr;
        return false;
    }
    BOOL bRet = WriteFile(hVolume, buffer, sectorSize, &bytesWritten, NULL);

    if (!bRet)
    {
        long lastErr = (long)GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "WriteFile returned 0 error " << lastErr;
        return false;
    }

    if (bytesWritten != sectorSize)
    {
        long lastErr = (long)GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Written bytes different than expected " << lastErr;
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hVolume);
    return true;
}

Now this function is executed without errors only if the position parameter is less than 1 Mbyte (1024 * 1024). If it is equal or higher than this value, it gets the error 5 - Access denied - after executing the WriteFile.
But there is an important detail: if I write in the first sector of the flash I destroy the FAT and immediately after Windows Explorer says that the drive needs to be formatted.
I understand that writing the flash using low level drivers is a destructive test; however I don't want to corrupt the FAT itself and format the drive after every test.
Is there a way to write at addresses higher than 1024 * 1024?

GetLastError() return DWORD. Use std::to_string to convert to string.

I think you need to specify FILE_SHARE_READ as well (so that others are allowed to read as well): FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE.

As a side note, I would generally be suspicious about using things like GetLastError() or errno as part of a larger C++ expression -- you never know what might have happened before it even gets there. Did you try reading the GetLastError before constructing the error message -- is it still 0 then?

I have tried to change to FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE: same result. I checked GetLastError() as a first thing after the call to WriteFile(): it is zero

There are three writeSectors. Did it fail on the first one? What about testing   a different drive?

@Minxin Yu - MSFT - It failed the same way on the three writeSectors. I haven't tried yet with other flash drives. As soon as I do it I will post the result
